# when i try to uv unwrap my mesh , blender hangs and become unresponsive, why?

Tags: texturing, uv, sculpting

I am new to blender, when i try to uv unwrap my mesh, blender hangs and become unresponsive. the mesh has nearly 35000 faces. it is a subdivided sphere which i used for sculpting. 
when i uv unwrap a simple cube , it works fine. is there a workaround for this, or a better alternative way to apply texture?

Comment: Which option are you using to unwrap your mesh?

Comment: i used both the normal unwrap and sphere unwrap

Comment: i have also increased the TdrDelay of the graphics card to 10, but it still becomes very slow. is this problem only limited to me? can you do uv unwrapping for large models in blender?

Comment: While blender is processing the interface will freeze up. Try giving it a few minutes. Or subdivide after unwrapping.

Comment: That may be dependent on your computer configuration or blender version.

Comment: yes, as gandalf3 said, i first unwrapped the sphere and then subdivided it, and it didn't hang this time, but became a bit slow.

Answer (score 1):

### Potential Solution: Smart UV Project

---

Although I've never tested this method on a UV Unwrap task that has crashed Blender, I've found that using the 'Smart UV Project' option is much faster using the normal 'Unwrap' function.

I found this when unwrapping the mesh of an ANT Landscape body, where it would take several unresponsive seconds before Blender processed the unwrap using the regular unwrap function. 
However, when I unwrapped again using the 'Smart UV Project' option (with the default parameters), it was almost almost instantaneous.

I know this is a pretty old post but I'll leave this here just in case anyone finds it and gets help from this answer. (Hope I haven't broken any community forums by 're-opening' an 'archived' thread.)

Answer (score 0):

To whom it may concern:

I had this problem, and my error was that my .obj file contained duplicated vertices. Unwrapping wouldn't finish in an hour even. But then I found that I needed to go into edit mode, select all, and right click -> merge vertices -> by distance (default settings worked fine). After this preprocessing (which also reduced the file size - I won't complain about that) the unwrapping finished in a matter of minutes. Additionally, in my case, "Smart UV Project"  (with an island margin of 0.001 just to be safe) turned out to give much better (more compartmentalized) results, and after merging vertices, this operation didn't take more than a couple of seconds.

Just to be clear - even the smart uv projection didn't terminate until I tried merging vertices. Merging the vertices is key.